# Handling big objects in Angular (typing etc.)

Tags: angular, typescript

Using http I get an array of huge objects. This object contains a lot of values, some of them I don't even care about.

Object (`...` is equal to different values I don't need):

```
id: '45678',
attributes: {
  title: 'This is a title!'
  ...
},
resources: [
  {url: 'www.facebook.com', type: 'social media', ...},
  {url: 'www.instagram.com', type: 'social media', ...},
],
...
```

Let's say I have a component I need to display the value stated above and ignore the rest (`...`). What's the best practice here?

Do I create a new array, map the old one and solely push a manipulated object with only the data I need? What about typing and creating interfaces in Angular, do I need to cover all objects?

EDIT:

```
return this.http.get(this.url)
  .pipe(
    map((a: any) => {
      const products = [];
      a.items.map(obj => {
        products.push({id: obj.id, resources: obj.resources, attributes: obj.attributes});
      })
      return products;
    })
  );
```

Comment: I wouldn't map the old array to create a new one. You would add another layer of abstraction, need more computation time, without simplifying anything. Regarding the interface/type: you can omit properties that you don't need, there wont be any compiler issue, but it might be confusing why you omitted certain properties.

Comment: @acincognito: That sounds like a good answer. Why don't you post it as such? Then we could upvote it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Angular `HttpClient` you've probably will get an `Observable<YOUR_OBJ_TYPE[]>`

You can just use the rxjs `map` operator and then map the array objects, should look something like that:

```
httpClient.get<YOUR_OBJ_TYPE[]>('URL')
     .pipe(map((res:YOUR_OBJ_TYPE[])=> res.map(
      (obj: YOUR_OBJ_TYPE) => {
        id: obj.id,
        attributes: obj.attributes,
        resources: obj.resources,
        ...
})))
```

Comment: Thanks! I just added code to the question - do you mean like this?